# How to use ttest with np.vectorize across multiple 3d arrays

Tags: python, numpy

im a bit confused on how to implement a t-test across elements of multiple 3d arrays with np.vectorize.

Goal: So, take three arrays with the same dimensions and size and apply a t test across one element from each in identical positions, creating another array with the same dimensions and size as the original three, with the results

To start road required libraries

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
```

Consider,

```
#create 3 toy 3d arrays
a = np.array([[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]])
b = np.array([[[13,14,15,4], [1,6,9,10], [1,0,.5, .2]]])
c = np.array([[[0,0,1,2], [1,1,3,4], [4,1,11,17]]])
```

[In a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75597666/conduct-one-sample-t-test-across-each-element-of-multiple-t-test/75598059?noredirect=1#comment133394023_75598059) I learned, about the vectorize function to conduct operations on across the arrays.  Like so:

```
# Define the function to apply to the arrays
def some_function(x, y, z):
    return f'result: {x} {y} {z}'

# Apply the function to the arrays using numpy.vectorize()
result = np.vectorize(some_function)(a, b, c)

# Print the result
print(result)
```

To conduct a t test, a a 1 dimensiuonal array it is pretty trivial.

```
eg = np.array([1,2,3,4])
t_statistic, p_value = stats.ttest_1samp(a=, popmean=5)
t_statistic
```

Where i am getting lost is how to integrate that into the example use of np.vectorize.

When I try:

```
def t_func(x,y,z):
    return stats.ttest_1samp()

out = np.vectorize(stats.ttest_1samp(a,b,c, mean = 0))
```

We get:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `numpy`'s vectorization to `t_func`:

```
def t_func(x,y,z):
    return stats.ttest_1samp(a=[x, y, z], popmean=0)

t_func = np.vectorize(t_func)
out = t_func(a, b, c)
```